# Python/Pandas: Selecting dataframe rows with multiple conditions - col 1 matches col 2 OR col 3

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

If I have a df like so:

```
dfdict = {'1': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b'], '2': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a'], '3': ['b', 'a', 'd', 'c']}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(dfdict)

    1   2   3
0   a   a   b
1   a   b   a
2   a   c   d
3   b   a   c
```

I want to save only the rows where `col 1` matches `2` OR `1` matches `3`. In this case, rows 0 and 1 would be saved:

```
    1   2   3
0   a   a   b
1   a   b   a
```

I tried:

```
   df2 = df1.loc[df1['1'] == df1['2'] & df1['1'] == df1['3']]
```

but I get error `TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'bool'`.

I would also like to get the other lines where `col 1` does NOT match `2` OR `3`, i.e. rows 2 and 3, in a separate df.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Option 1**
`eq`, fixing your code,

```
df1[df1['1'].eq(df1['2']) | df1['1'].eq(df1['3'])]

   1  2  3
0  a  a  b
1  a  b  a
```

---

**Option 2**
`np.vectorize`

```
f = np.vectorize(lambda x, y, z: x in (y, z))
df[f(df1['1'], df1['2'], df1['3'])]

   1  2  3
0  a  a  b
1  a  b  a
```

Comment: Option 1 works great for the case of saving those rows. What about getting the rows where `col1` does not  equal `2` or `3`?

Comment: @Liquidity If you are familiar with boolean algebra, that's just inverting the condition: `~(df1['1'].eq(df1['2']) | df1['1'].eq(df1['3']))`.

Comment: That gives me a df with False for the first two rows and True for the last two, not the rows themselves.

Comment: @Liquidity Obviously! You use that mask to index `df`... `m = ~(df1['1'].eq(df1['2']) | df1['1'].eq(df1['3'])); df2 = df[m]`, sorry, I thought that was a given.

Comment: Sign...I can only help to vote it up , but the downvoters should revisit correct this kind 'unfair' behavior for the people who provide good answer , man .